# Errors with Opera 12.11 -- can't access google

Tags: security

Latest Opera 12.11  Am getting the following error when attempting to access http://www.google.com
It works fine with all other browsers, so it is an Opera issue.  Problem only started with 12.11.

Unable to complete secure transaction

You tried to access the address "http://www.google.com/", which is currently unavailable. Please make sure that the web address (URL) is correctly spelled and punctuated, then try reloading the page.

Secure connection: fatal error (10) from server.

https://www.google.com/

Transmission failure.
Make sure your internet connection is active and check whether other applications that rely on the same connection are working.
Check that the setup of any internet security software is correct and does not interfere with ordinary web browsing.
If you are behind a firewall on a Local Area Network and think this may be causing problems, talk to your systems administrator.
Try pressing the F12 key on your keyboard and disabling proxy servers, unless you know that you are required to use a proxy to connect to the internet. Reload the page.
Need help?
Open the Opera Help.
Go to Opera's online support desk.

Answer (score 1):

Me too.  Fixed it by deleting .opera directory which was evidently corrupt. The directory is regenerated next time Opera is used.